# How to evaluate emprical cdf at given points in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a sequence of scalar points subject to a unknown distribution.

From the sequence of points, we can get the empirical cdf.

I was wondering if there is some way in Matlab to evaluate this empirical cdf at any point? For example, evaluate it at the same sequence of points that are used to build the empirical cdf?

I have looked up the function `ecdf` at http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ecdf.html. Its usage is `[f,x] = ecdf(y)`, where the empirical cdf from data y`is evaluated at`x`, but`x` doesn't seem to be specifiable.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I think `f` is evaluated at the same sequence of points used to create it...? To get it at another point `p` try `interp1(x, f, p)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the output of the function, two vectors `f` and `x` and you want to find the emperical cdf at point `x_of_interest`, this is what you can do:

```
max(f(x<=x_of_interest))
```

Or maybe you want to use `min`and `>=`, but I think the above formula is correct.

Comment: you suggest "zero-hold" (or 'nearest') interpolation. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to use more "smooth" interpolation here?

Comment: @ Shai For estimating the CDF, yes then i would recommend something smooth. For the emperical CDF, probably not judging from this image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Empirical_CDF.png

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin  Could you elaborate a little on this point, or provide a reference to understand what would be the best interpolation approach in this case and why?

Comment: @Giuseppe This question is on how to get the emperical CDF. Whether using that (or any alternative) is a good approach is a question on an entirely different level. What I could recommend is that you try to make sure you know what you want, and then check the wiki in the comment above to see if the ECDF does that. If you are unsure after that, consider asking a question on mathoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `x` are unique points in `y` with their CDF.

Comment: I think `x` and `f` are unique points on the CDF? And `y` are the observed values that include the residuals still?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's what you meant, but I also needed to convert a vector of data values to the corresponding vector of empirical CDFs, with the same ordering.

Actually, instead of the usual definition `cdf(x) = Prob(X <= x)` I prefer the more symmetric definition `cdf(x) = Prob(X < x) + 1/2 * Prob(X == x)` , which is more suitable to cases with ties. Now the computation is a one-liner, but with the help of the `tiedrank()` function from the statistical toolbox:

```
cdf = (tiedrank(data) - 1/2) / length(data) ;
```

For example,

```
data = [3     2     4     2     1] ;
```

yields

```
cdf = [0.7    0.4    0.9    0.4    0.1] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach might be to use interpolation to find the closest "x" for each point you want to evaluate, and the relative "f" value. You can find how to use interp1 for this purpose here:
[determining-the-value-of-ecdf-at-a-point-using-matlab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046476/determining-the-value-of-ecdf-at-a-point-using-matlab)